# How to generate a super XML node

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xbase

I have the following XML snippet:

```
<topic>
  <data attribute1="1">some data 1<data>
  <data attribute1="1">some data x<data>
  <data2 type="sometype">some data 2</data2>
</topic>
<topic>
  <data attribute1="1">some data 1<data>
  <data attribute2="2">some data 2<data>
</topic>
```

I'd like to generate a super XML node from these `topics`such that the final output is a single `topic` with elements grouped by attribute, element names and values:

```
<topic>
  <data attribute1="1">some data 1<data>
  <data attribute1="1">some data x<data>
  <data2 type="sometype">some data 2</data2>
  <data attribute2="2">some data 2<data>
</topic>
```

What's the best approach to achieve this? Could I use XQuery? I've been playing around with http://basex.org/ but not had much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying your input XML to make it a valid XML file with a root element and closing tags like this

```
<root>
    <topic>
        <data attribute1="1">some data 1</data>
        <data attribute1="1">some data x</data>
        <data2 type="sometype">some data 2</data2>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <data attribute1="1">some data 1</data>
        <data attribute2="2">some data 2</data>
    </topic>
</root>
```

you can merge all sub-nodes of the `<topic>` elements in one `<topic>` element with this XQuery:

```
let $file := doc("a.xml")/root 
return
  <topic>{for $item in $file/topic/* return $item}</topic>
```

Its output is

```
<topic>
    <data attribute1="1">some data 1</data>
    <data attribute1="1">some data x</data>
    <data2 type="sometype">some data 2</data2>
    <data attribute1="1">some data 1</data>
    <data attribute2="2">some data 2</data>
</topic>
```

which differs from your expected output. But because you didn't specify any rules for the output, this is as good as it gets.

Comment: The answer you marked as answer doesn't do any grouping. 

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky: Yes, it doesn't, because no grouping criterium was specified (as mentioned in the last sentence of my answer).

Comment: @zx485 I did mention `such that the final output is a single topic with elements grouped by attribute, element names and values` is this not grouping criteria in your opinion? I'd appreciate if you could explain how I could group the nodes.

Comment: Just open a new question